# How can I reverse .reshape() and get back to a 3D array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape, pca

I have a dataset of shape (256, 180, 360). I reshaped it to 2D, removed the 0 values, and applied PCA using:

```
data = data.reshape(data.shape[0], data.shape[1] * data.shape[2]).T
data = data[~np.all(data == 0, axis = 1)]
# Dataset is now of shape (27719, 256)

data = StandardScaler().fit_transform(data)
pca = PCA()
transformed = pca.fit_transform(data)
```

Now, the next step is to reshape the transformed dataset back to 3D and plot the PCA results. I tried:

```
transformed.reshape(360, 180, 256)
```

which gives me the error "cannot reshape array of size 7096064 into shape (360,180,256)". I understand I cannot get back to the original shape because I removed 0 values which changes that shape, of course, but I have tried other variations of this alongside using variations with the transpose but I cannot get it back to 3D (not necessarily the exact dimensions as before). Any recommendations?

Comment: What do you expect it to do?  How do you want it to fill in the extra rows?  You can try `.reshape(-1,180,256)` to have it create as many planes as it can, but if there aren't 360 rows, the numpy has no idea what you want.

Comment: I thought it was implied I wasn't expecting to get the original shape back, just a 3D array

Comment: .reshape(-1,180,256) gives me the same error btw :(

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

What you can do in this scenario is to not use `fit_transform`, and instead have two separate pipelines. One that uses `fit` to train on the dataset with all the zero entries removed, and then use `transform`s on the *original* dataset to get your transformed data.

```py
flat_data = data.reshape(data.shape[0], data.shape[1] * data.shape[2]).T
nonzero_data = flat_data[~np.all(flat_data == 0, axis = 1)]

scaler = StandardScaler()
pca = PCA()
pca.fit(scaler.fit_transform(nonzero_data))

transformed = pca.transform(scaler.transform(flat_data)).reshape(data.shape)
```

Comment: Hmm interesting. I do not exactly follow what the last two lines are doing? Would you be willing to elaborate on that?

Comment: @DiscJockey7733 It applies the learned transformations to the original data.